# Python "scraping" maps/images

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to use Python to scrape snapshots of maps/images of properties. I have the post code for all of the properties I need to get maps/images for, but I am unsure how to use Python to take the postcode, search a website, take a snap shot of the map and then save it.

I had initially thought to use Selenium, but not sure this would be the most efficient way to search the websites?

Only been learning Python a few months so would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction!

Comment: Can you share example of page `URL`? with expected output description. Also show what have you tried already

Comment: @Andersson, 1 example - http://maps.environment-agency.gov.uk/wiyby/wiybyController?x=357683.0&y=355134.0&scale=1&layerGroups=default&ep=map&textonly=off&lang=_e&topic=floodmap - I would like to save a screen shot and then extract some of the text from "Text only version" on the top right hand side. In all honesty, I have not tried anything for this yet.  This is the next project on my radar and I was hopping to get a few ideas to explore before I start. I think being fairly new to Python, this has been hardest to find resources on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Google's static maps API like so:

```
import requests

zoom = '13'
size = '600x300'
maptype = 'roadmap'

scheme = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=[Location]&zoom={0}&size={1}&maptype={2}'.format(zoom, size, maptype)
locations = ['Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY', '2550+SW+Hillsboro+Hwy,Hillsboro,OR', 'TX+78016']  # place, address, state+zip

for loc in locations:

    url = scheme.replace('[Location]', loc)
    resp = requests.get(url)

    print('Status code: {0} | {1}'.format(resp.status_code, url))

    if resp.status_code == 200:

        with open('map_image_{0}.png'.format(loc), 'wb') as f:

            f.write(resp.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy may be a good choice as well. It does take some initial setup to 'start a project' and currently the most recent stable release is for Python 2.7 (support for Python 3 is underway).

If your interested in trying Scrapy here is the documentation:

and a quote how Scrapy can pull images from files: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.3/index.html

"Scrapy provides reusable item pipelines for downloading files attached to a particular item (for example, when you scrape products and also want to download their images locally). These pipelines share a bit of functionality and structure (we refer to them as media pipelines), but typically you’ll either use the Files Pipeline or the Images Pipeline."

I just started with Scrapy as well and have setup and begun writing Spiders (their web crawler) and can help you get set up if your interested.